# Django forms автогенерируемое поле

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Никогда не работал с django, использовал Flask и поэтому возникла проблема.

У меня есть сущность

```
class Storage(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, name="name", help_text="Название")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, name="description", help_text="Описание")
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=63, name='author', help_text='Автор')
    path = models.CharField(max_length=63, name='path', , unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.description[:25]}"
```

Для создание сущностей пользователям сайта существует форма:

```
class StorageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Storage
        fields = ["name", "description", "author"]
        widgets = {
            "name":         TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder":"Input name"}),
            "description":  Textarea(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder":"Description"}),
            "author":       TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder":"Your name"})}
```

Соответсвенно view.py

```
def new_storage_area(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = StorageForm()
        context = {"form": form}
        return render(request, "st/new.html", context)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StorageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

      
        else:
            pass  # TODO If form is not correct
```

Но есть одно но:
Поля name, description и creator  пользователь должен вводить в форме, а path должно генерироваться автоматический при помощи PathManager.newpath()
Не могу понять как это сделать. Как я понял мне нужно переопределить **init** метод у Storage, так, что бы он автодополнял это поле при создании. Или нужно как то модифицировать полученый form?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Действиельно, можно было просто перегрузить **injt**()

Ответ нашел вот [тут](https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelformrelationships.html)

Мой код

```
class Storage(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Storage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.path = self.generate_path()
```